I went to see him to/at his house
Consider these sentences of mine, please:

I went to see him to his house.

I went to see him at his house.

Please come for your interview to room number 3.

Please come for your interview in room number 3.


Which are correct between 1 and 2, and 3 and 4?
As far as I know, it should be "go/come to a place", and not "go/come at/in a place".

You could say "I went to his house to see him", but go to see someone has a special meaning of pay them a visit and doesn't follow the usual rule for go on its own. So (2) is correct and (1) isn't.

Seeing someone to someplace means to ensure that they get there. #1 means “I made sure he got to his house,” which I don’t think is what you intended. #2 means “I visited him at his house,” which is probably what you intended.
#3 means “Please come to room 3, where your interview is” while #4 means “Please come to your interview, which is in room 3.” There is no real difference in meaning - the only difference is that #3 says your destination is room 3 and adds the additional info that your interview is there, while #4 says your interview is your destination and adds the additional information that it is in room 3.
